# Griffiths Intro to QM Section 9.1.3: How did he get this answer and am I misunderstanding something?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

In Section 9.1.3 Griffiths develops time-dependent perturbation theory, but I don't understand how some extra terms are popping into his equations.

I searched around for some answers and found [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/238317/griffiths-intro-to-qm-section-9-1-2-what-type-of-approximation-is-he-using-here?rq=1), which explains how Griffiths is getting his approximations by taking
$$c_a(t)=c^{(0)}_a(t)+λc^{(1)}_a(t)+λ^2c^{(2)}_a(t)+\dots \hspace{5mm}(*)$$ $$c_b(t)=c^{(0)}_b(t)+λc^{(1)}_b(t)+λ^2c^{(2)}_b(t)+\dots\hspace{4mm}(**)$$

This did clear up my confusion on how Griffiths was getting Equations 9.17 and 9.18 (One can find more details in the link), but it also conflicts with the claim that Griffiths makes in the following paragraph:

> The error in the first-order approximation is evident in the fact that $|c^{(1)}_a(t)|^2 + |c^{(1)}_b(t)|^2 \neq 1$ (the *exact* coefficients must, of course, obey Equation 9.5). However, $|c^{(1)}_a(t)|^2 + |c^{(1)}_b(t)|^2$ *is* equal to $1$ *to the first order of $H'$*...

Equation 9.5: $|c_a(t)|^2 + |c_b(t)|^2 = 1$.

But looking at $(*)$ and $(**)$, shouldn't it be the *sum* of the zeroth and first approximations? I mean:

$$|c^{(0)}_a(t)+c^{(1)}_a(t)|^2 + |c^{(0)}_b(t)+c^{(1)}_b(t)|^2 = 1$$

Why does he assume that the first order should "take in" the extra term from the zeroth order?

My thinking is that I'm understanding something wrong here with how Griffiths is naming/doing his approximations. But I don't see how he can derive Equations 9.17 and 9.18 without the method described in the post I read through earlier.